# Developing a separate UI for flutter web from same codebase developed for mobile

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-web, code-reuse

I have developed a mobile application using flutter and it works perfectly on ios and android.what I want to do now is to get the web app also from the same codebase but with a different ui.The current application perfectly runs on the browser as well, but its weird since I have used mobile specific components like bottom navigation. I have developed this with **BLoC pattern** and the ui is separated from the business logic. My question is, can I develop the ui for web application and reuse the business logic implementation in the existing code? If can, I am happy if anyone can provide some references that I can use.

Comment: You can use the constant `kIsWeb` to check if your app is running in web.

Comment: @rickimaru this also can be taken as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can take advantage of your Blocs and just reimplement the UI.

As @rickimaru suggested you could check if `kIsWeb`. But my advice would be to check your screen size instead. As flutter is getting more targets like windows, linux, macOS etc.

It's probably more appropiate to construct a different UI for bigger screens not just for web(unless you perform logic specific to the web platform , but it does not seems like the case). Also just running on web does not imply bigger screen size, your users could be visiting via their phones browser.

You could manually check for screen sizes using a `MediaQuery` and breakpoints or you could take advantage of already made packages like [responsive_framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework).